# How to manipulate user files without uploading to the server first?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible with AS3 to prompt a file select screen to the user, get the selected file data and use it directly in the movie without the need to upload this file to the server first and then get it back? I want something like FileReference to enable the user to selected many image files then I want to display/manipulate these images directly in the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native filesystem access is not permitted in Flash applications due to security issues. AIR bridges this gap while not compromising the security.

Comment: Native filesystem access is permitted when using FileReference. I'm wondering if I can access the data directly before uploading it to the server. I don't want to directly access the filesystem, the user will select it, as with FileReference.

Comment: In flash, FileReference will only give you the filename, not the full path. Try it out.

Comment: OK but I was wondering if there was another solution similar to FileReference, not FileReference itself. But it seems there isn't, right?

Comment: No. What you are trying to do *is* filesystem access -- a strict no-no.

Comment: FileReference under AIR will give you the full path, in a browser app you will only get the file-name. So, your only choice is to upload to a server.

Answer (score 2):

I heard that in flash player 10, you actually can do this. I have not tested it myself, but I've seen a couple of demo videos. Here's something that google found that might be relevant.

http://dynamicflash.com/2008/07/flash-player-10-local-file-access/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

See http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/